# GoalsWidget should show all goals

Tags: reactjs, frontend

Currently, if I want to see all "goals", I have to click on "Expand" button.

Three "goals" fit in a row.

[Not expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GiPk.png)

[Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSLfL.png)

What I have to do is remove "Expand" button and make sure that all "goals" are visible in a widget without that button.

What should be done there?

```
return (
<>
  <Grid container spacing={1}>
    {mapGoals(goals.slice(0, GOALS_TO_FIT_IN_ROW))}
  </Grid>
  {shouldCollapse && (
  <>
    <Collapse in={openCollapse}>
      <Grid container spacing={1}>
        {mapGoals(goals.slice(GOALS_TO_FIT_IN_ROW, goals.size))}
      </Grid>
    </Collapse>
    <ExpandButton open={openCollapse} setOpen={setOpenCollapse} />
  </>
  )}
</> );
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

the code should be

```
return (
<>
  <Grid container spacing={1}>
    {mapGoals(goals)}
  </Grid>
  
</> );
```